# How do I hide or display Ul when we click on a Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I click on a Div Ul that I've put into it is displayed. Note that the code:

```
<div class="menu-item">menu title</div>
<div class="plus"></div>
<div class="minus"></div>
<ul class="sub-item-menu">
<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

</ul>
<div class="menu-item">title</div>
<div class="plus"></div>
<div class="minus"></div>
<ul class="sub-item-menu">
<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

<a href="index.php"><li>text</li></a>

</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.plus').click(function () {
    $('.sub-item-menu').slideDown();
    $('.plus').fadeOut(200);
    $('.minus').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('.minus').click(function () {
    $('.minus').fadeOut(2);
    $('.sub-item-menu').slideUp();
    $('.plus').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Css Code Is:

```
.plus {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(images/plus.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-27px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.minus {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(images/minus.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-27px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.menu-item {
    background:url(images/menu-asli.png) repeat-x;
    width:197px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:1px;
    font-family:"B Yekan";
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-right:3px;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
.sub-item-menu, .sub-item-menu2 {
    margin-top:3px;
    width:198px;
    margin-right:1px;
    display:none;
    font-family:"B Yekan";
    font-size:14px;
}
.sub-item-menu a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sub-item-menu li {
    background:#ff0084;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding-right:3px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

But when I click on one of the menus and sub ​​menus, sub-menus display both shows.

tnx.

Comment: Your markup is incorrect.  Do not wrap the li with a elements.  The structure should be `<li><a href="index.php">Text</a></li>`

Comment: ahhh that code is impossible to read!! Clean it up please

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, I'm having trouble understanding your English.

Comment: Try this:http://jsfiddle.net/e94gU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as Ed mentioned above. Or organize your code better and then use the `siblings()` function

Put your HTML in organized `divs` and clean up the `li`'s

```
<div class="menu-item">menu title
    <div class="plus">+++</div>
    <div class="minus">---</div>
    <ul class="sub-item-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu-item">title
    <div class="plus">++</div>
    <div class="minus">--</div>
    <ul class="sub-item-menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Use `this` and `siblings()` to find the elements with the class you want in the jQuery

```
$('.plus').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.sub-item-menu').slideDown();
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
    $(this).siblings('.minus').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('.minus').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(2);
    $(this).siblings('.sub-item-menu').slideUp();
    $(this).siblings('.plus').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nG53w/1/

Note: I did have to change your plus and minus CSS to make them appear properly because I dont have access to the background images. Just put yours back in and delete the text in the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors will pick up all elements with that class. so this:

```
$('.sub-item-menu').slideDown();
```

Will slide down both elements with that class.

You need to give them different id's and use ID selector instead.

```
 $('#sub-item-menu1').slideDown();
```

Or change your second sub-item-menu div to have class sub-item-menu2 which is mentioned in your css but not in your markup.

And you also need to differentiate between your plus and minus links in a similar manner.

```
$('.minus').click(function () {
```

Will respond to a click on both of those elements.